# Does Google-charts or Google-visualization angularjs support zoom in features?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I have this plunker code which creates a line chart using Google charts with angularjs.

http://plnkr.co/edit/IgMRq50OcMuSWxZZSKHd?p=preview

According to google-chart documentation, google-chart supports features like zoom in and zoom out.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?hl=en

However, I am not sure if the angularjs version of google-chart supports zoom features as the documentation is mainly in the form of code examples.

How can the plunker code be extended to support zoom features, if possible?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'googlechart' ]);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        var chart1 = {};
        chart1.type = "LineChart";
        chart1.data = [
           ['Component', 'cost'],
           ['Software', 50000],
           ['Hardware', 80000],
           ['H1', 40000],
           ['H2', 30000],
           ['H3', 20000],
           ['H4', 50000],
           ['H5', 70000],
           ['H6', 80000],
           ['H7', 40000],
           ['H8', 30000],
           ['H9', 20000],
           ['H10', 10000],
          ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make use of the `Explorer` object in your options.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?hl=en#configuration-options), go to the explorer part. It's sufficient to just an add empty `explorer:{}` to your options variable to start experimenting with it in your chart.

Comment: How to do it in angularjs?

Comment: In your link you add your options at this part `chart1.options = {
        displayExactValues: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        is3D: true,
        chartArea: {left:10,top:10,bottom:0,height:"100%"}
    };`, so adding `explorer:{}` gives you the explorer function. But you'll have to configure it to make it work like you want it to (I believe).